# Testing method call from for loop for EasyMock Java

Tags: java, junit, code-coverage, easymock

```
List<ValidAddress> validAddress;
for(validAdd : validAddress)
 {
   if(validAdd.getValue()!=0)
    {
      //do some action
    }
 }
```

Here I need to use EasyMock to test the getValue() method.
I am writing as below:

```
EasyMock.expect(validAdd.getValue()).andReturn(1D).anyTimes();
```

So in place of `validAdd` , how can I provide the object which will iterate the loop.

`getValue()` returns double.

Comment: If you want to test `getValue()` of `ValidAddress` class, make sure you don't mock `ValidAddress` in your test class. Ideal way to test this is to make a List of actual `ValidAddress` instances and then test the method.

Answer (score 0):

If you want to mock `getValue`, it means that the list of `ValidAddress` are all mocks. You need to set the expectation on each of these mocks.